# Should we remove small, humorous parts in answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, humor

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15347275/2) edit was made to my answer, which I have since rolled back. When I saw it, I was offended by it - yes, it was a joke, but it didn't take away from the quality of the answer at all - it was in its own paragraph at the bottom of the answer!

The joke wasn't offensive in any way, and it is highly unlikely that anyone would attempt to call the fake phone number in the answer, so how was it a "bad joke"?

I feel like people take this site way too seriously sometimes - so, should by we allow these types of small, amusing parts in answers?

Comment: What exactly do downvotes mean to a question like this? "No, we shouldn't allow this", or "this has been asked before", or "I hate jokes"?

Comment: With the title and question as they are, I assume they can both mean "No, we should not remove those" and "Yeah, we absolutely should. They don't belong"....take the one you're happiest with I guess. :)

Comment: I think the downvotes are because they didn't like *your* joke. FWIW, I think that joke would've been much funnier if you stopped it halfway through.

Comment: The downvotes mean "I don't like people named Richard". Or "I don't like people with blue gravatars". Or "Hey, I haven't downvoted in a while, let's see if this still works". Or "I disagree with this. What do you mean which part? ALL OF IT!". Or "Crap, question tagged [humour], I don't even have to read it to know it's bad". Take your pick. It doesn't matter. This is Meta, and Meta means murder.

Comment: @yannis yeah? Well I hate y - nope, I love you.

Comment: Ah, yet another love - hate relationship. Story of my life <sigh>

Comment: Apparently you forgot that Stack Overflow is [where we hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: @Servy Ah, dammit, let me change my answer.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Did you call that fake number yourself? Perhaps what that ends up calling might provide you with an explanation.... :)

Comment: Indeed, [this is how we feel about fun here](http://memeorama.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/i-had-fun-once-it-was-awful.jpeg)

Comment: On another note, is the misspelling of warranty purposeful? I almost edited it..

Comment: Definitely depends on the joke, and the nature (humour can be employed to make points memorable). This attempt just seems entirely irrelevant, and particularly _unfunny_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't mind a bit of humour in posts, as long as it does not distract from the actual content. In this case I don't think anyone can argue that it does.

Would I have deleted that paragraph? No. I can however see though how, especially because it's a separate paragraph, someone might see that as unnecessary fluff. As such I would personally not have rolled it back if someone were to remove such an attempt at humour from me.

In general I'd say that a bit of humour, if kept to a minimum and if not distracting, is fair enough. As long as the main focus is the content.

Answer (score 1):

All too often it seems that the community forgets that we are people writing these answers. If you start removing the humor and other flair that people add to their answers, you start removing the human.

I personally upvote any answer that makes me chuckle. Sometimes a well placed nit of humor is what makes one answer superior to another.

Though i don't think that there is any reason to remove humor, I can still understand someone wanting to.

I don't think any kind of regulation on this kind of editing is going to be able to be policed and I don't think it would serve anyone.

Was the answer better with the humor? well the community should decide, and if the community, or in this instance one member of it, decided the answer was better without it, then so be it.

Sadly there are times when we can't be as human as we want to be...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm totally human.

Comment: see you get it.